# Hosting React website on AWS Cloudfront using the index.html

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web, amazon-cloudfront

I am currently learning how to develop websites on React, and I have a webpage built. I ran the npm run build to get the index.html file, when I open the index.html file it opens as a blank page, so then I saw somewhere else that you have to use npm run-script deploy to get the localhost url and the on network url, these both work. But my question now is that when I upload my files to an AWS S3 bucket and host it on AWS Cloudfront it uses the index.html file and once again shows up as a blank page when I use the URL. How would I fix this? Is there some other file I should be using so that it isn't blank? Something I should add to the index.html to load the other components of the react project? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a deploy module like this one? https://www.npmjs.com/package/deploy-aws-s3-cloudfront